# How to claim royalties for product design and coding after the fact, when I did not negotiate an arrangement beforehand

Tags: work-environment, intellectual-property

I am currently working as a sales representative for a company.

A customer requested the company to  create a product 2 years ago (even before I started working there), and the company has never been able to get the product working.

I spoke to the customer and put some thought into the product, did my research and decided that everything will work.
I then called the owner to say I have some of the parts and that I only need 2 things to get it working, and I can also write software for the product.  The owner said to speak to accounts and order the products you need.  The company paid for a few items and I supplied the rest.

I started working on the product over the weekend in my personal time and it works perfectly.  It only needs to do site testing but everything works correctly.

I want to claim royalties or something to protect the work I have done, as this does not fall under my job scope at all.

I still need to build the final product for site testing and I want to make sure of my facts before I approach the owner.
Can anyone please help.

Comment: What does your contract say about collecting royalties?

Comment: My contact doesn't state anything about rolayties or even product design I did even get a permanent contact

Comment: Then you will not be collecting any.

Comment: I doubt that product engineers would collect royalties on things they designed and implemented.

Comment: It's a good question; unfortunately it is at least partly off-topic since it's a legal question. On the other hand, understanding what to expect as an employee is on topic, and good answers are possible without getting into the details of the law even if the ultimate answer has to be "nail this down before signing and/or ask your lawyer ".

Comment: Maybe a language barrier, but royalties aren't claimed, they are negotiated. The problem is, if your company already owns the work you've done, you have nothing to negotiate with.

Comment: Your employment agreement covers this. Often that agreement states that anything you develop while an employee is owned by the company no matter if you create it on weekends or during the week.

Comment: @ChristopherBoyd I've edited your question make it read better in English.  If you don't think what I have done is not correct, you can reject the edit and change it all back to before.

Comment: A country tag would maybe help getting appropriate answers, AFAIK it's typical in US software industry is that anything created out of work hours still belong to the company, but it's rarely the case here in Europe (but there might be legal issues working for a client of your company outside of your work). Anyway it's more a legal question and what's in your contract

Comment: You don't say if you've informed anyone else as to the success?  If not - then ethics and morals aside - claim it needs more work and then negotiate based on the need for you to do that further work in your own time.  Don't be surprised if your employer says, 'that's ok. work on it in company time and maybe you'll get a bonus.'

Comment: Another clarifying question: "this does not fall under my job scope at all" - why do you think this? For salaried work in my country (UK) anything you do on company time at the instruction of your employer is "under your job scope". The contract may set out an expectation of your responsibilities, but they can ask you to do whatever they like (putting aside obvious exceptions like crimes).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're right I should have been more precise, as I don't know the laws for all European countries. Here in france it would be illegal to produce work off the clock for your job (if it's for your job, it must be paid and would be overtime instead of off the clock). But it's standard to have non-compete agreements here so that to do job for a company client should require your company's agreement first

Comment: In "The company paid for a few items and I supplied the rest" which company is this? The one you work for, or the customer's? When you spoke to the customer, did you do it in the name of your employer, or as personal off-the-clock project in your own name? Who do you want to claim something from? The customer or your employer?

Comment: When you spoke to the customer, did you say you worked at your employer or did you procure the contact independently and present yourself as an interested private person?

Answer (score 41):

If you wanted to do this, you needed to have a discussion about it with your employer before you started doing any work for it (even on your own time) and absolutely 100% before they paid for anything.

If you think there is actual money in this, go and pay to talk to a lawyer who can advise you what chance of have of having any kind of ownership of this - but I wouldn't hold out much hope.

Answer (score 20):

### Your company will almost certainly own the rights to the product.

Your benefit from making the product is the salary you received while creating it.  No company will pay its employees for products they create as employees, and certainly not for existing customer requests.

Your company needs to license and distribute the product.  If it has never sold software products before it  probably needs to retain a lawyer to help with the Software Licensing Agreement.  Sale of the new product will be through the company's sales organization.

Comment: However: He made it in his own time. They may own the rights to the product, but they first need to get it. They dont know how much is finished, or the state of it. If they want a *good* product from OP, there might be some leverage (as long as he hasnt handed it over)

Comment: Does it matter if he used his own hardware?

Comment: @Martijn Most contracts have provisions for this: it is an idea they generated when talking to a client, they got permission from the owner and resources from the company. This is clearly a work directly related to their daytime employer, the fact that they did it in their own time is unlikely to allow them to claim ownership.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel He was in sales, though, rather than engineering.  There's a good chance that *his* contract didn't have anything of the sort.

Comment: @BenBarden In sales you have probably even **stronger** provisions in your contract regarding stealing clients and competing with your own employer, so I don't think that will fly.

Comment: Stealing clients and competing?  That's fair.  That's not really what was under discussion, though, and sales isn't all that likely to have the same provisions wrt things like patents.

Answer (score 14):

> I started working on the product over the weekend in my personal time
> and it works perfectly. It only needs to do site testing but
> everything works correctly.
>
> I want to claim royalties or something to protect the work I have
> done, as this does not fall under my job scope at all.
>
> I still need to build the final product for site testing and I want to
> make sure of my facts before I approach the owner. Can anyone please
> help.

Ask the owner of the company if you can get royalties or something (most likely a bonus). The answer will almost certainly be "No", but if you don't ask you will never know.

Do it now before the final product is complete.

It doesn't matter if creation of the product fell under your job scope or not, you chose to develop the product, and products developed for the company and their clients are usually property of the company, unless another arrangement was agreed upon beforehand.

Answer (score 13):

Now that you've done the work, it's probably too late to negotiate a bonus for that. Your employer will argue that you did all this during (paid or unpaid) overtime, so all intellectual property belongs to the employer. You could perhaps consult a lawyer and ask if they can find a legal argument that entitles you to IP ownership and ask them for an estimation of cost and success chance if you would press that argument in court. But I (as a legal layperson) wouldn't assume that the chances are good. And besides, getting into a legal dispute with your employer is rarely a good career move. At least if you intend to stay there.

All you can probably do is bring it up during your next performance review / contract renewal negotiation and argue for a raise.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to look at other questions here and on the Law stack about intellectual property rights.

Generally, in a work-for-hire situation, the rights are part of what you are being paid to produce, and are owned by the company until and unless the company agrees to give them to you. This should be spelled out explicitly in your contract (at least in the US). The employment contracts I've seen explicitly recognize that work unrelated to the company's products, services, and processes will probably be not be claimed and will be returned to the employee, but it's up to the company to decide whether the idea is in their space or not.

You can try to negotiate the details of your contract before signing to limit that, but they can tell you that they won't hire you unless you agree, at which point all you can do is sign or walk away. Once you have signed, you are legally bound by that agreement. You can try to fight it in court but doing so will be a Career-Limiting Action.

If you are a contractor rather than an employee, your contract may say that the company only gets what you have been explicitly contracted to deliver. It may even say they don't own that, but are being given a perpetual license to use it. That's something you need to negotiate  before taking the job, and carefully write into the contract. Make sure you have your own lawyer review the contract before signing it; you can be certain the customer's lawyers will, and details of wording may matter. (I've mentioned before that my father got burned by trusting that a customer's lawyer would write a contract that wasn't biased in the customer's favor.)

Once it's clearly yours, if it ever is, you can decide how you are going to sell it -- license usage and collect usage fees of some sort (details determined by the specific license the customer purchases), sell some or all of the rights outright in exchange for royalties (details determined by the sale contract), or sell some or all of the rights for a fixed sum. Or a combination. Note that in the latter two cases you give up ownership, and may have to purchase a license yourself if you want to continue using it.

Also, look up an explanation of derivative rights; once it is sold, even if you come up with a new version you may not be able to do anything with it unless the current owner of the intellectual property agrees... which means they may be your only possible market for those improvements. Again, this is an area where you may want to consult your own lawyer, preferably *before* you sign any agreement.

In your particular case, from what you've said, your work is probably the company's to do what they wish with, including leaving it owned but unused if that's what they prefer. They are paying you, in part, for your creativity; what they have paid for is theirs until and unless they say otherwise. Check your contract. Check company policy. Ask a lawyer if in doubt. You can try for one of the other options when negotiating the contract for your next job.

The company may certainly decide to give you a bonus or raise or promotion in recognition of your work. That's entirely up to management, as guided by company policy. No guarantees, but generally if you are producing things they consider especially valuable they will want you to stay and will probably find a way to encourage you to stay and continue to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

### The Royalty Ship has sailed. Focus on what you can get in the future.

Your only hope of getting any royalty money from what you have done hangs on whether you can prove that you did the work on your own time and whether the law in your jurisdiction cares about this. Ask nicely and accept their answer; forcing the issue will get lawyers involved, which will eat up most of the money and all of the goodwill.

**But**

You can parlay this into a better position with your current employer. If and when they ask for any more software development, point out that you are currently a sales representative with no official software development duties, and that further software work will require re-classification of your position (so that the software work may be done in the office on company time), and an increase in your *salary*.

Answer (score 0):

I worked for a large US company, but in the UK, and one rather clever guy working there obtained a number of patents for himself, regarding compression techniques. Unfortunately, I am not aware of the specifics of the legal agreement that he had with the company, in order for him to have achieved this.

Nevertheless, from [Who Owns Patent Rights: Employer or Inventor?](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/who-owns-patent-rights-employer-inventor.html#:%7E:text=The%20general%20rule%20is%20that,or%20to%20create%20the%20invention.)

> ##### Employers Routinely Control Employees' Patents
>
> The general rule is that you own the patent rights to an invention you
> create during the course of your employment unless you either:
>
> - signed an employment agreement assigning invention rights, or
> - were specifically hired (even without a written agreement) for your inventing skills or to create the invention.
>
> In practice, one of those two exceptions almost always applies, thus
> ensuring that employers hold the patents to their employees'
> creations. Almost all sophisticated employers, particularly those
> hiring workers at chemical companies, technology firms, or design
> companies, require employees to sign [pre-invention assignments](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/pre-invention-assignment-agreements.html) at the
> time of their hire. These are often included in the employment
> documents that an employee will fill out on his or her first
> day—documents that probably also include [nondisclosure](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/nondisclosure-agreements-29630.html) and
> [confidentiality agreements](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/sample-confidentiality-agreement-nda-33343.html).

So, unless you were particularly diligent on your first day there,  (as others have already stated) you probably signed away your rights there and then.

Answer (score -3):

I'm going to go against the other answers here:

### Even though ideally you would have negotiated before hand, there's still a chance that you can get some money and good contacts out of this.

I'm basing my answer on this:

> I started working on the product over the weekend in my personal time

You say you created the "object of value" in your free time? There is a chance that this means it is still legally yours. This will all depend on where you live (there was no country tag on the question) and what is stipulated in your contract (for example: some contracts say that everything created while employed is legally the company's. How enforceable this is is a country for Law SE).

There's also the fact that the work is 1) not finished, 2) not in the hands of the employer. So you do have some trump cards here. Without explicitly threatening to do so, there's a risk for the employer that you will just stop working on it, or never deliver the work. That means you still have some room for negotiating here. In fact, it might have strengthened your position. Because before you made it you didn't know how good your work was going to be. Now you do. And you can use this knowledge in your negotiations about a price.

Comment: I know where you're going with this, but it's seriously undermined by "The company paid for a few items".

Comment: @PhilipKendall not at all. The company can send their invoice if they wish to be compensated for the items. From OP's post, OP contributed the majority of the items. He also did not yet invoice the company for those. Providing items does in no way affect the ownership of an outcome.

Comment: @Opifex That's again going to depend on jurisdiction to a great extent. Certainly in the UK, working with any office equipment can be a fact suggesting that something was created in the course of your employment.

Comment: @origimbo which is exactly what I wrote in my answer. It depends on the country and the contract. There is no country tag and no mention of a clause in the contract. So your assumptions about it being related to the UK are baseless.

Comment: Additionally, regardless of the law: OP has some huge trump card in his hands which puts him in a strong negotiation position. Even if the law and/or contract is in favor of the employer.

Comment: Playing that "trump card" is hazardous. See my comments about "career limiting action."

Comment: @keshlam Hazardous, sure. But still a trump card that you hold. What you do with it is up to you. It can also lead to a great relationship between company and employee.

Comment: In my country (the Netherlands), this won't fly. Everything I do in my spare time that can be regarded as part of my work is owned by my employer. I'd have to negotiate a special clause in my employment contract to change this.

Comment: @reinierpost: I work for a Dutch company. This is indeed a standard clause in most contracts in our country. However, these are seldomly enforceable. Especially in OP's. case. But as a I said several times now: even if they would apply (which isn't sure yet, because OP did not add the Netherlands-tag), OP *still* has a big trump card. Even if the company legally already owns all the rights. This is an important point you're all ignoring.

Comment: @Opifex: Card, I grant. Trump, I doubt... Or if so it's to a fairly low card in the trump suit and not especially likely to beat the cards the company holds, at least in most of the US. Elsewhere may or may not be different  Before playing "you bet your job", know what laws actually apply in your particular case.

Comment: @Opifex: The trump card is to hold the company's assets hostage. That's what it is in legal terms. Now the company may of course choose to ignore this, but if I were the company, I wouldn't be inclined to be friendly with an employee who tried to pull this trick on me.

Comment: @reinierpost there's a lot more in between giving them your work for free, or holding their assets hostage. They are not aware of what you have made. Is it a 100% finished product? a POC? Some experiments? Or a total failure? 
You on the other hand *do* have this information. If the company asks you to deliver, you can deliver whatever you want.But... if the company wants a finished product there's still plenty of room for negotiation."Want me to finish the POC into a finished product? Sure! I can do that! I made the POC as a gesture to the company, but from here on I need to be compensated."

Comment: @Opiflex Legally, it's their work not yours, even when they're not aware of it. What you can legitimately negotiate without appearing like a fraud is a budget to turn your proof of concept into something that is production quality and of value to the company. So that's the road I would take in this situation.